# Creating edges for NetworkX in python efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-structures, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe which has unique identity of a person and last name. I want to make edges between all persons with the same last name. How do I do it efficiently?

Sample Dataset:

```
Identity,LastName
1,Beckham
2,Singh
3,Bagari
4,Shukla
5,Sharma
6,Singh
7,Beckham
8,Beckham
9,Singh
```

Output: 
(1,7) , (1,8) , (7,8) , (2,6) , (2,9) , (6,9)

I want to build a network where there is an edge between identities (1,7) , (1,8) , (7,8) , (2,6) , (2,9) , (6,9)

I can iterate over all the identities and then create edges but it takes a very long time for 5,000,000 odd records? Is there a better solution for the same?

Comment: What is you expected outcome?  A list, dataframe, tuple?

Comment: Expected output can be a tuple or a list of identities connected together. For the above example it will be like : (1,7) , (2,6)

Comment: Can you have more that two people with the same lastname and do you want all combinations of two's?

Comment: Yes we can have more than 2 people with the same last names and I want all possible combinations of the two's. I was thinking that I can create a dictionary which will have key as the lastname and values as the identity, but then how would I create a tuple from there?

Comment: You are going to need to build a more robust test case.

Comment: Just edited the sample for a better test case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `groupby` with `combinations` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations
s = df.groupby('LastName')['Identity'].agg(lambda x: tuple(x.tolist()))
s[s.apply(len)>1].apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2))).sum()
```

Output:

```
[(1, 7), (1, 8), (7, 8), (2, 6), (2, 9), (6, 9)]
```

### Update:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
list(chain(*df.groupby('LastName')['Identity'].agg(tuple).apply(combinations, r=2)))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 7), (1, 8), (7, 8), (2, 6), (2, 9), (6, 9)]
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the reply,  this code generates a list of all the identities associated to the last name , so I get an output like :    Beckham (1,7,14,15,17,21) . I want all possible combinations: like (1,7) (1,14) (1,15)(1,17) (1,21) (7,14) (7,15) (7,17) (7,21)  and so on ....

Comment: Hi Scott, this takes a lot of time to create tuples for 5,000,000 records, is there any thing I can do to run it parallely in python (may be use pyspark)? or some other way I can generate combinations faster?

Comment: Let's get some numpy help. add numpy to your tags in the question.  Or create a new question with numpy tag.